# Change Color of every element dynamically in Star Rating

Tags: html, css, angular

I have implemented star rating and it works well. Now requirement is to have different color  for each star where in my star color comes from CSS and its colored as GOLD. How can I give it different colors. for example - 1st star should be red, second blue, third green and so on..

```
<fieldset class="rating">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let star of starList">
        <input type="radio" id="th {{star.id}} {{j}}" name="th_{{j}}" (click)="updateRating(star.value,kpi.kpiId)" />
        <label [class]="star.class" for="th {{star.id}} {{j}}" [title]="star.value"></label>
    </ng-container>
</fieldset>
```

Css:

```
.rating {
    border: none;
    float: left;
    direction: ltr;
}

.rating>input {
    display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    display: inline-block;
    content: "\f005";
    font-weight: 900;
}

.rating>.half:before {
    content: "\f089";
    position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
    color: #ddd;
    float: right;
}

.rating>input:checked~label,

/* show gold star when clicked */  

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,

/* hover current star */ 

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
    color: gold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Please add the corresponding code to the question to make a working example of what you have, this helps the SO community to better answer your question. [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: make class name also dynamic like class1, class2 ,class3 .. and give style for each class

Comment: I have updated the css as well. Please Have a look Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this an example how you can achieve this simply create a class for each stage from 1 star to 5 star

```
.rate-1 label:nth-child(1){
  background: red;  
}

.rate-2 label:nth-child(1) ,.rate-2 label:nth-child(2){
  background: orange;  
}

.rate-3 label:nth-child(1) ,.rate-3 label:nth-child(2) , .rate-3 label:nth-child(3){
  background: blue;  
}

.rate-4 label:nth-child(1) , .rate-4 label:nth-child(2) , .rate-4 label:nth-child(3) ,.rate-4 label:nth-child(4){
  background: yellow;  
}


.rate-5 label:nth-child(1) , .rate-5 label:nth-child(2) , .rate-5 label:nth-child(3) , .rate-5 label:nth-child(4) , .rate-5 label:nth-child(5){
  background: green;  
}
```

template

```
<fieldset class="rating" [attr.class]="'rate-'+selectedValue">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let star of starList" >
        <label>
           <input type="radio" [value]="star" (click)="updateValue(star)"/> ★
        </label>
    </ng-container>
</fieldset>


{{selectedValue}}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-54003602)

Comment: This is great ! Can you please help me with the css that I just updated in my Question ?

Comment: can you create a stackblitz demo base of you code @AniketKulkarni so I can check it ?

Comment: No worries, I solved it. Thanks again for the help ! @malbarmawi

Answer (score 0):

check below code may be it will help you :

```css
.yellow{
  color:yellow
}
.purple{
  color:purple
}
.blue{
  color:blue
}
.green{
  color:green
}
```

```html
<div [ngClass] = "noOfStars==1 ?'yellow':noOfStars==2?'purple':noOfStars==3?'blue':noOfStars==4?'green'"></div>
```